# C Preprocessor Expansion to another object-like macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, limit, c-preprocessor

I have code like the following (Mixed C/C++ application)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE UINT16_MAX
```

I was expecting `BUFFER_SIZE` to be (65535) like `UINT16_MAX` is defined in stdint.h but instead the compiler complains the `UINT16_MAX` was not defined. Obviously the macro expansion isn't happening as I would like.

I could just define it myself to (65535) but would like to know why this doesn't work.

Response to a couple comments:

- My compiler does support the `uint16_t` type and `UINT16_MAX` is defined in stdint.h
- One person mentioned defining `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` - I have tried defining this before including stdint.h to no effect.

**ANSWER**

So it was the `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` but more complicated.

1. The #define was in a header file (which included stdint.h)
2. I had #define `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` in this file prior to including stdint.h
3. I included that header file in another source file. This other source file also #include
   stdint.h and did so prior to including my header. Therefore when stdint.h was first included `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` was not defined

My solution was just to add `-D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` to my compiler arguments.

Comment: Try including `limits.h`

Comment: @VoidPointer - `UINT_MAX` is defined in `limits.h`, but `UINT16_MAX` is defined in `stdint.h` (**if** the implementation provides an exact 16-bit unsigned type).

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html shows no such definition but..

Comment: Does your compiler support `uint16_t`? That's not required to exist.

Comment: @VoidPointer - sure it does. "Maximum values of exact-width unsigned integer types: {UINTN_MAX} Exactly 2^N -1". Replace `N` with the number of bits.

Comment: The answer does not belong in the question itself. Please remove the answer from the question, and post it as a stand-alone answer. It is fine (and encouraged) to self-answer your questions when you can answer them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you seem to be using C++ you might do:

```
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
```

From `/usr/include/stdint.h` of a recent Debian:

```
/* The ISO C99 standard specifies that in C++ implementations these
   macros should only be defined if explicitly requested.  */
#if !defined __cplusplus || defined __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS

...

/* Maximum of unsigned integral types.  */
# define UINT8_MAX              (255)
# define UINT16_MAX             (65535)
# define UINT32_MAX             (4294967295U)
# define UINT64_MAX             (__UINT64_C(18446744073709551615))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are including the C header from a C++03 file, then you will need to define `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` before including the header; otherwise it may not define these macros.

If you're using C++11, then include the C++ header `<cstdint>` instead.